# I set ui datepicker to disable all day before tomorrow, but the hours?

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, datepicker, calendar, hour

I disable ui datepicker all days before tomorrow with "minDate: 1", but I have problems with the hours because the slide hours starts in 00:00.
I use js/jquery/ui/datepicker.min.js?ver=1.11.4 in Wordpress.
Example, today is February 21 and is disabled before tomorrow, it is 23:00 pm hours, but as the slide of the hours starts at 00:00. The user can select Febrery 22 at 00:00, only one hour before and not 24 hours before or one day.
How can I do this? 
I put code and pictures below:

```
        $('.departure-date').datetimepicker({
            minDate: 1,
            // minTime: '12:00',
            // maxTime: '11:59',
            teFormat: window.datepickerDateFormat,
            altFormat: window.datepickerAltFormat,
            altFieldTimeOnly: false,
            showMillisec: false,
            showMicrosec: false,
            showTimezone: false,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            altField: "#dep",
            addSliderAccess: true,
            sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: true },
        });
```

[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pjNb.jpg) and [example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8rZn.jpg) Can someone help me please?

Comment: where did you get this datepicker?

Comment: in a wordpress template, "Transfers Theme"

Comment: is it free? without seeing full code of this plugin we cannot say what to do, but it would be great if there is an option to set something like startDateTime - then you could set this dynamically as current datetime + 24 or 25 hours

Comment: correctly!
version: jQuery DateTimePicker plugin v2.4.1
homepage is: xdsoft "dot" net / jqplugins / datetimepicker/

Comment: I have tried many things but nothing works for me. I searched all over the internet but nobody talks about this and I think it's an important issue for datepicker.
Thanks for answering

Comment: GREAT :-) Its Work for me

Comment: No work. Im sorry. :-(

Comment: The slide of the hours in ui datetimepicker should start at the current time.
I was wrong because I was at 00:45 am and I got confused, it does not work yet

Comment: https://www.icex.es/icex/ficheros_estaticos/js/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js;72526
the formula is in hourMin: hourMax: Timezone: etc..

Comment: did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some holes in documentation so looking into the plugin code I found way to do what you want. Two options:

1. Add just one line to params array you have (change X to hours amount):

   ```
   minDateTime:(new Date()).setTime((new Date()).getTime() + (X*60*60*1000)),
   ```
2. Before call your datetimepicker calculate minDateTime and then add short line to params array:

   ```
   var startDate = new Date();
   startDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() + (X*60*60*1000));

   $('.departure-date').datetimepicker({
       minDateTime: startDate,
       ...
   });
   ```

Comment: It's great. ¡Great job!. :-) thank you very much and I hope that this code will help more colleagues.